# Why a mixed nash equilibirum is a correlated equilibrium

Tags: game-theory

As stated in Tim Roughgarden's book "twenty lectures on algorithmic game theory" (on page 176), "***the mixed nash equilibrium of a game correspond to the correlated equilibrium that are product distributions***" .

Put it mathematically.

***Consider a cost-minimization game and a product distribution $\sigma=\sigma_1 \times \cdots \times \sigma_k$ over the game’s outcomes, where $\sigma_k$ is a mixed strategy for agent $i$. Prove that $\sigma$ is a correlated equilibrium of the game if and only if $\sigma_1, \cdots, \sigma_k$ form a mixed Nash equilibrium of the game.***

I can prove the direction from CE to MNP given the product distribution condition.
Specifically, from the CE definition, given $\sigma$ as a CE, we have
\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\mathbf{E}_{\bar{s} \sim \sigma }[C_i(\bar{s}) | s_i] \leq \mathbf{E}_{\bar{s} \sim \sigma }[C_i(s^\prime_i, \bar{s}_{-i}) | s_i],  \forall s_i, s^\prime_i  
\end{equation}
where $s_i$ denotes the strategy of the $i$th player, $\bar{s}$ denotes the joint strategy, $ s^\prime_i$ denotes a deviation of $i$th player from the CE.

Given the product distribution condition $\sigma=\sigma_1 \times \cdots \times \sigma_k$, the above equation can be expressed as
$$
\mathbf{E}_{\bar{s}_{-i} \sim \sigma_{-i}}[C_i(s_i, \bar{s}_{-i})] \leq \mathbf{E}_{\bar{s}_{-i} \sim \sigma_{-i}}[C_i(s^\prime_i, \bar{s}_{-i})],\forall s_i, s^\prime_i   
$$
where $\sigma_{-i}$ denotes $\sigma_1 \times \cdots\sigma_{i-1} \times \sigma_{i+1} \cdots \sigma_k$.

It follows that
$$
\sum_{s_i}\sigma_i\mathbf{E}_{\bar{s}_{-i} \sim \sigma_{-i}}[C_i(s_i, \bar{s}_{-i})] \leq \sum_{s_i}\sigma_i \mathbf{E}_{\bar{s}_{-i} \sim \sigma_{-i}}[C_i(s^\prime_i, \bar{s}_{-i})] , \bar{s}_{-i})],\forall s^\prime_i  
$$
and
$$
\mathbf{E}_{\bar{s} \sim \sigma}[C_i(s_i, \bar{s}_{-i})] \leq \mathbf{E}_{\bar{s} \sim \sigma}[C_i(s^\prime_i, \bar{s}_{-i})] , \bar{s}_{-i})], \forall s^\prime_i , 
$$
which is the definition of MNP.

However, I failed to prove the inverse direction, i.e., from MNP to CP.
Could anyone help me out.

Thank you in advance.